# Generar un SELECT para verificar aciertos de un juego de azar con MySQL

Tags: mysql, date

Tengo las siguientes tablas.

Tabla `JUGADOS`

```
| Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra
+------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
| FECHA      | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |
| SERIE      | bigint(12)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| J1         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| J2         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| J3         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| J4         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| J5         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| J6         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
| JUGADOSID  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
```

Tabla `SALIDOS`

```
 Field      | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra
------------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------
 FECHA      | date             | YES  |     | NULL    |
 SERIE      | bigint(14)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S1         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S2         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S3         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S4         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S5         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S6         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 S7         | tinyint(2)       | YES  |     | 0       |
 SALIDOSID  | int(10) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment
```

La tabla `JUGADOS` guarda jugadas por fecha, las jugadas son `6` números que van del `0` al `45`, y no se repiten. Esos `6` números, se guardan cada uno en los campos `J1` al `J6`. El campo serie lo que guarda es la formación de esos `6` números, por ejemplo, si se jugó `3,10,21,25,31,37`, la serie va a ser `31021253137`. La relación con la tabla `SALIDOS` es el campo `fecha`.

En la tabla `SALIDOS` va el sorteo que se realizó en la fecha de la tabla `JUGADOS`, y por cada fecha hay 3 salidas, un ejemplo sería:

Tabla: `JUGADOS`

```
Fecha        Serie              S1   S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
03/04/2016   4,14,15,22,26,39    4   14  15  22  24  39
```

Tabla: `SALIDOS`

```
Fecha        Serie              S1   S2  S3  S4  S5  S6
03/04/2016   4,11,22,26,32,38    4   11  22  26  32  38
03/04/2016   4,12,23,27,33,39    4   12  23  27  33  39
03/04/2016   5,13,24,27,34,39    5   13  24  27  34  39
```

En este ejemplo la cantidad de aciertos que tuvieron los números jugados fueron `4`, porque los números de la tabla `SALIDOS`, se pueden repetir, pero solo se toman en cuenta los que no se repiten, en el ejemplo se repite el `4`, el `27` y el `39`.

Lo que necesito crear es un `SELECT` que me devuelva los aciertos que tuvo cada una de las jugadas de la tabla `JUGADOS` dentro de un rango de fechas de la tabla `SALIDOS`. Por ejemplo saber cuántos aciertos tuvo cada jugada de la tabla `JUGADOS` entre el `01/01/2016` y el `31/12/2016` de la tabla `SALIDOS`.

---

Gracias .... pero no funcionó, de esa manera me retorna todas las jugadas, es como si hubiese hecho:

```
SELECT * FROM JUGADOS
```

Sustitui el `LEFT JOIN` por `INNER JOIN` y me devuelve "**Empty Set**" (probando desde la línea de comandos), pasa lo mismo si lo hago con `RIGHT JOIN`.

Concretamente lo que necesito es por ej.:

Los números 1,10,21,22,28,36 que se jugaron el día 27/03/2010 tuvieron 5 aciertos dentro de los 18 números que salieron el día 02/04/2016, los números 6,13,14,30,34,39 que se jugaron el día 16/01/2008 tuvieron 4 aciertos
dentro de los 18 números que salieron el día 28/07/2016, etc., etc.
Gráficamente seria algo como:

```
Números jugados      Fecha        > Cant Aciertos  Fecha > acierto

1,10,21,22,28,36   27/03/2010         5               02/04/2016

6,13,14,30,34,39   16/01/2008         4               28/07/2016
```

Después lo puedo ordenar por la columna de mayor cantidad de aciertos y por la fecha del máximo acierto, pero en principio lo más difícil es encontrar la forma para que salga de esta manera.
Lo que hay que tener en cuenta es que son 18 números que salen para la misma fecha de la jugada, y 6 que se juegan, y que dentro de los 18 números solo se toman una vez si se repiten, o sea que si el día 02/04/2016 salieron los números `1,11,21,23,29,37 | 1,13,24,29,36 | 2,10,20,22,40,42`
en el ejemplo se repiten el 1 y el 29, y para evaluar los aciertos se tomarían los números `1,11,21,23,29,37,13,24,36,2,10,20,22,40,42,` o sea en lugar de 18 números se toman 16.

### 06/01/2017

```
SELECT (
  IF( 
        COALESCE(j1.j1,0)>0,1,0)
    +IF(COALESCE(j2.j2,0)>0,1,0)
    +IF(COALESCE(j3.j3,0)>0,1,0)
    +IF(COALESCE(j4.j4,0)>0,1,0)
    +IF(COALESCE(j5.j5,0)>0,1,0)
    +IF(COALESCE(j6.j6,0)>0,1,0)
    ) AS aciertos
FROM jugados AS j 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(s1) AS j1 
   FROM salidos 
   WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
   ) AS j1 ON j.j1=j1.j1 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(s2) AS j2 
   FROM salidos 
   WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
   ) AS j2 ON j.j2=j2.j2 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(s3) AS j3 
   FROM salidos 
   WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
   ) AS j3 ON j.j3=j3.j3 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(s4) AS j4 
   FROM salidos 
   WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
   ) AS j4 ON j.j4=j4.j4 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(s5) AS j5 
   FROM salidos 
   WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
   ) AS j5 ON j.j5=j5.j5 
 LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT DISTINCT(s6) AS j6 
   FROM salidos 
   WHERE fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
   ) AS j6 ON j.j6=j6.j6 
 WHERE j.fecha BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-12-31'
 ) ;
```

Comment: ¿Cual es la pregunta? ¿Tienes algún problema específico?

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio Antorio. Cuando tengas que agregar información a tu pregunta, selecciona la opción [edit] y agrégala allí. Te recomiendo revisar el [tour] y [ask].

Comment: Podrias dar el ejemplo de lo que te devolvio al realizar la consulta? con los left join, para darme idea

Comment: Revisa lo que añadi a la respuesta :D

Comment: Resuelveme una duda, los números jugados, j1, j2... no deben de coincidir con s1, s2 ...., puesto que la consulta cambiaría completamente

Comment: Lo que tengo que saber es cuantos de los números jugados estan dentro de los 18 que salieron en tal fecha, a nivel programación seria el equivalente a recorrer la tabla JUGADOS con un ciclo WHILE y a su vez cada uno de los registros que tiene esa tabla JUGADOS chequearlos con la tabla SALIDOS.

Comment: *Los números 1,10,21,22,28,36 que se jugaron el día 27/03/2010 tuvieron 5 aciertos dentro de los 18 números que salieron el día 02/04/2016*: ¿Qué tiene que ver la fecha `27/03/2010` con la fecha `02/04/2016`? Pensaba que las fechas debían corresponder entre las 2 tablas. No entiendo.

Comment: la tabla JUGADOS es la que recepciona las apuestas de los jugadores, que para este caso corresponde a 6 números del 0 al 45 que no se repiten y la tabla SALIDOS es la que tiene los números que salieron por fecha de sorteo. Los números del sorteo son 18, que si se pueden repetir, pero en el caso de que se repitan solo se toma uno de esos. Volviendo al ejemplo de antes, si en la tabla JUGADOS hay una jugada que tiene 1,10,21,22,28 y 36 y en el sorteo de la tabla SALIDOS estan los números 2,10,20,21,29,37,3,11,22,23,40,41,5,6,22,28,29,36, la cantidad de aciertos es 5, el 10,21,22,28 y 36.

Comment: Es un juego parecido al superball de USA, con la diferencia de que en lugar de 4 números (según me fijé en la página) son 6.

Comment: Ya probaste con la nueva consulta? ya la modifique

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente la última consulta que posteaste.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Después de todo llegue a esto

```
select j.FECHA AS FECHA_JUGADA, CONCAT_WS(',',J1,J2,J3,J4,J5,J6)AS NUMEROS_JUGADOS,
IF(INSTR(s1.s, concat(',',j.J1,','))>0,1,0)
+IF(INSTR(s1.s, concat(',',j.J2,','))>0,1,0)
+IF(INSTR(s1.s, concat(',',j.J3,','))>0,1,0)
+IF(INSTR(s1.s, concat(',',j.J4,','))>0,1,0)
+IF(INSTR(s1.s, concat(',',j.J5,','))>0,1,0)
+IF(INSTR(s1.s, concat(',',j.J6,','))>0,1,0) AS ACIERTOS,
s1.FECHA AS FECHA_NUMEROS_SALIDOS
from JUGADOS as j, (
    select 
    concat(',',group_concat(concat_ws(',',S1,S2,S3,S4,S5,S6)),',')AS s, FECHA 
    From SALIDOS WHERE FECHA BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
    group by FECHA) as s1 
WHERE j.FECHA BETWEEN '2016-01-01' AND '2016-01-03'
    ;
```

Los números los concateno todos por igual, ya que no importa si estan duplicados se toman en cuenta, solo busco que este dentro de la cadena, `INSTR` lo que hace es buscar la cadena y devuelve un 0 si no esta y un número mayor en caso de encontrar, alli obtienes los aciertos :D

Comment: Me sale este error: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1. Ahora escribo la consulta tal como la escribi en la línea de comandos.

Comment: A mi me ejecuta correctamente, pero solo obtiene los aciertos, tomando que j1 coincide con s1, y consecutivamente

Comment: Funcionó perfectamente la solución planteada por Hammerffall BK. Gracias era exactamente lo que necesitaba. Me refiero a la última de las 2.